# Ensuring Network Stablity

Tags: ethernet, internet, lan

I recently became the IT guy at a remote school with onsite staff. The network setup is a bit messy right now. I am curious about the best standards to use. Below is a map of the current network that provides internet.

[image: Network Map]

As you can see, the network is a bit of a mix of methods. There is one Ethernet cable running underground along the lines. There is a coaxial cable running from the satellite on the roof to the modem located next to the server.

I often run into weak connections further out, especially at 19 and 23 which will drop out for days during sand storms, rain, or snow.

I have heard running dual lines helps. I was also thinking doing something like looping 19 back to the server to make one large circle. This would require a lot of work, but so would digging up the lines that are in place.

A central network location that all lines branch off of might also be an option. I have a lot of Wire.

What are some standards that could accomplish my goal?

Thanks!

-Joel

Comment: You need to edit your question to give a lot more detail. For instance, you write, "_one Ethernet cable_," but you don't say which type of cable (UTP, STP, MMF, SMF, etc.). You need to give as much detail as possible including distances. If an ethernet cable goes out because of weather, it wasn't installed correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably running into distance limitations of Ethernet over copper.  If you're going to dig, then you should use fiber-optic cable instead of copper.    It's more expensive, but not a big increase compared to the cost of digging.

Regardless of what you choose, you will need to use network switches instead of hubs, especially at 23 and 26.   That will also solve your distance problem.

Comment: I wonder why sand storm affect the signal inside the coaxical cable. Don't you thing that if it is true that the sand on the surface of the cable is so harmful, buring the cable into the sand would stop the communication completely?

Comment: Maybe you have loose connections that move when the wind is blowing?

Comment: Coax cable?  What kind of switches/hubs are you using?

Comment: It is becoming much more interesting now. You basically say that in order to fix the plug connections we must switch to the optical cable. It is really non-trivial solution. You must be a true professional :)

Comment: It's not a trivial problem ;-)  I mention optical because you mentioned digging.  The cost of digging is much more than the cost of the fiber.  If you can't afford to dig, there are other possibilities.  We would need to know what kind of hubs/switches you have now, for starters.

Comment: When you say that you mentioned "optical because I mentioned digging" says that you can actually see the future :) This explains your's non-trivial capabilities to solve the non-trivial problems :).